# Can I change img src in css dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images say `theImg_enabled.gif` and `theImg_disabled.gif`. I need to change the `img src` dynamically. How can I do that in css?

```
 <img class="changeImg" src="theImg_enabled.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>

<style>
    .changeImg {
                      // I need src="theImg_enabled.gif"
    }

    .changeImg.disabled {

                      // I need src="theImg_disabled.gif"
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with CSS (it can be done with JavaScript).

However, if the image was displayed not as an `<img>` element but as the [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image) of some other element, you could do so by changing that CSS property (**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/kUaQt/)**).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that by using CSS, you need to use client side scripting such as JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("my_id").src="URL";
```

However if you are having a background image of an element, and you want to change that on hover, you can certainly write something like

```
div {
   background-image: url('SRC');
}

div:hover {
   background-image: url('SRC2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css of img but u have to use javascript. So change src of img in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a value in *img src*, you cannot change it using CSS.

Solution 1

```
<img class="changeImg" />  
<style>
    .changeImg {
        border:0;
        width:16px;
        height:16px;
        background-image: url('theImg_enabled.gif');
    }
    .changeImg:hover  {
        background-image: url('theImg_selected.gif');        }
</style>
```

Solution 2:

```
    <a href="." class="changeImg" /> 
    <style> 
        .changeImg a {
            display:block;
            width:16px;
            height:16px;
            background-image: url('theImg_enabled.gif');
         }

         .changeImg a:hover {
            background-image: url('theImg_selected.gif');
         }
    </style>
```